# PHP code for profile views, Ideally 1 view per IP per hour, any way to achieve this?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a small social network and was wondering if I could limit the views on user profiles to 1 view per IP per hour so users don't abuse their views by simply refreshing.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality using php? Can somebody please provide any hints on how to do it?

Comment: Please add your ideas about what all did you try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create columns in table to store all the details like last visit and clients ip address.
2. You can get client ip address by using $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'); or by using $_SERVER.
3. Store ip address and last visit time in table with user_id whose profile is being viewed.
4. Write query like select last_visit_time from tablename where ip_address = $clients_ip_address
5. Get current time by using date() function
6. Check difference between last_visit_time and current time, if the difference is more than 1 hr, Show error message.

Hope this logic will work. Let me know if you try this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely give that a shot, sounds like a solid approach, i'll let you know how it goes